# Java method to find a name variable starting with a given string from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have made an ArrayList.txt which contains a list of students with their grades, a separate class student containing `getName()`, `getGrade()`, `getMarks()` etc and on my main class, I have a main method which will pull from this method

Hence my method goes as this:

```
public static String findName(ArrayList<Student> o, String name) {

    for(int i = 0; i < o.size(); i++)
    {
        if(o.get(i).getName().startsWith(name.toLowerCase()))
            System.out.print(o.get(i));
    }
    return name;
}
```

and my main method has this
`findName(students, "al");`

my array.txt looks something like this

```
afafwafa
B
80
alicegg
C
70
lfhif
D
50
Allllleeee
A
94
```

however my `findName()` method is unable to pull all names that starts with "al" even though all my other methods are working. Also I need to take note that the method should be case insensitive and i need to use `.startsWith()`. Any suggestions?

To add on, with the given ArrayList of type student with a string file name, i need to create a method that will write the members of the arraylist to a text file with a given name with 1 element to a line using student class toString method format. i need to handle possible exceptions with try/catch. I also need to use either filereader, fileoutputsteam, printwriter, printstream in the code

```
public static void nameToFile(ArrayList<Student> a, String file) {      

    int i = inone.read();
    FileReader inone = new FileReader(a.get(i).toString());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    PrintWriter outone = new PrintWriter(fos);

    outone.close();
 }
```

my main method has this

`nameToFile(students2,"modified.txt");`

Comment: Put a `toLowerCase()` after `getName()` too?

Answer (score 2):

> Also i need to take note that the method should be case insensitive and i need to use .startsWith().

If you want your `startsWith()` method to ignore the case, just convert both to lower or upper case before comparison:

```
if(o.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(name.toLowerCase()))
```

If your `findName()` is supposed to just return 1 name, you can return it in the if-condition. If you want to return a list of names, add it to another arraylist, then return the arraylist.

Comment: adding a toLowerCase works! wow i did not realise it was that simple. thanks! as for writing member of ArrayList to a text file, any suggestions?

Comment: An alternative that I never feel gets enough credit is [`o.get(i).getName().regionMatches(true, 0, name, 0, name.length())`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#regionMatches-boolean-int-java.lang.String-int-int-).

Comment: @FinFin For writing you've got [all the methods of `PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) at your disposal. Note that `System.out` is a `PrintWriter` as well so you may already be familiar with the interface. You appear to be opening the output file correctly, all that's left is to `print[ln]` to your heart's content for each item you want to write, then close the file.